# Tikz television screen

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've tried to improve my Tikz skills - I've tried to make a simple figure. I wanted to try the foreach function out. But I have some trouble with the arranging of the blocks. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[margin=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{c11}{HTML}{C1BFC2}
\definecolor{c12}{HTML}{C0BF02}
\definecolor{c13}{HTML}{00C0C1}
\definecolor{c14}{HTML}{02BF01}
\definecolor{c15}{HTML}{BF00C0}
\definecolor{c16}{HTML}{C10001}
\definecolor{c17}{HTML}{0100C2}

\definecolor{c21}{HTML}{0300C3}
\definecolor{c22}{HTML}{141215}
\definecolor{c23}{HTML}{BF06C3}
\definecolor{c24}{HTML}{131418}
\definecolor{c25}{HTML}{00C0BF}
\definecolor{c26}{HTML}{140F13}
\definecolor{c27}{HTML}{C0C1BC}

\definecolor{c31}{HTML}{01204E}
\definecolor{c32}{HTML}{FEFEFE}
\definecolor{c33}{HTML}{34006C}
\definecolor{c34}{HTML}{141215}
\definecolor{c35}{HTML}{120403}
\definecolor{c36}{HTML}{151316}
\definecolor{c37}{HTML}{1E1C1F}
\definecolor{c38}{HTML}{141311}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach[count=\i] \col in {c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16,c17}
      \fill[\col] (10,40*\i) rectangle +(10,40);
\foreach[count=\i] \col in {c21,c22,c23,c24,c25,c26,c27}
      \fill[\col] (10,5*\i) rectangle +(10,5);
\foreach[count=\i] \col in {c31,c32,c33,c34}
      \fill[\col] (12,12*\i) rectangle +(12,12);
\foreach[count=\i] \col in {c35,c36,c37}
      \fill[\col] (4,12*\i) rectangle +(4,12);
%the last point [bottom right] is missing
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is how it should look like.

[image: Television screen saver.]

Kind regards!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just for fun, adding the TV set:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{c11}{HTML}{C1BFC2}
\definecolor{c12}{HTML}{C0BF02}
\definecolor{c13}{HTML}{00C0C1}
\definecolor{c14}{HTML}{02BF01}
\definecolor{c15}{HTML}{BF00C0}
\definecolor{c16}{HTML}{C10001}
\definecolor{c17}{HTML}{0100C2}

\definecolor{c21}{HTML}{0300C3}
\definecolor{c22}{HTML}{141215}
\definecolor{c23}{HTML}{BF06C3}
\definecolor{c24}{HTML}{131418}
\definecolor{c25}{HTML}{00C0BF}
\definecolor{c26}{HTML}{140F13}
\definecolor{c27}{HTML}{C0C1BC}

\definecolor{c31}{HTML}{01204E}
\definecolor{c32}{HTML}{FEFEFE}
\definecolor{c33}{HTML}{34006C}
\definecolor{c34}{HTML}{141215}
\definecolor{c35}{HTML}{120403}
\definecolor{c36}{HTML}{151316}
\definecolor{c37}{HTML}{1E1C1F}
\definecolor{c38}{HTML}{141311}

\definecolor{DGray}{RGB}{140,138,141}
\definecolor{LGray}{RGB}{229,227,230}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5mm,y=5mm]
\foreach \col in {1,...,7}
{
      \fill[c1\col] (10*\col,0) rectangle ++(10,-40);
      \fill[c2\col] (10*\col,-40) rectangle ++(10,-5);
      \ifnum\col<5\relax
        \def\Shift{-1cm}\def\Ancho{12}
      \else
        \def\Shift{19cm}\def\Ancho{4}
      \fi  
      \fill[c3\col] 
        ([xshift=\Shift]\Ancho*\col,-45) rectangle ++(\Ancho,-12);
}
\fill[black] (70,-45) rectangle ++(10,-12);

\coordinate (ul) at (10,0);
\coordinate (ll) at (10,-57);
\coordinate (ur) at (80,0);
\coordinate (lr) at (80,-57);

\filldraw[draw=black!70,top color=DGray,bottom color=DGray,middle color=LGray]
  ([xshift=-2.5cm,yshift=2.5cm]ul) -- 
  ([xshift=1cm,yshift=-0.5cm]ul) to[out=-93,in=93]
  ([xshift=1cm,yshift=0.5cm]ll) --
  ([xshift=-2.5cm,yshift=-2.5cm]ll) --
  cycle
  ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=2.5cm]ur) -- 
  ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=-0.5cm]ur) to[out=-87,in=87]
  ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=0.5cm]lr) --
  ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-2.5cm]lr) --
  cycle;

\filldraw[draw=black!70,left color=DGray,right color=DGray,middle color=LGray]
  ([xshift=-2.5cm,yshift=2.5cm]ul) -- 
  ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=2.5cm]ur) --
  ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=-1.5cm]ur) to[out=178,in=2]
  ([xshift=1cm,yshift=-1.5cm]ul) --
  cycle
  ([xshift=-2.5cm,yshift=-2.5cm]ll) -- 
  ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-2.5cm]lr) --
  ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=1.5cm]lr) to[out=182,in=-2]
  ([xshift=1cm,yshift=1.5cm]ll) --
  cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

The image for only the strips:

[image]

The code for just the strips:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{c11}{HTML}{C1BFC2}
\definecolor{c12}{HTML}{C0BF02}
\definecolor{c13}{HTML}{00C0C1}
\definecolor{c14}{HTML}{02BF01}
\definecolor{c15}{HTML}{BF00C0}
\definecolor{c16}{HTML}{C10001}
\definecolor{c17}{HTML}{0100C2}

\definecolor{c21}{HTML}{0300C3}
\definecolor{c22}{HTML}{141215}
\definecolor{c23}{HTML}{BF06C3}
\definecolor{c24}{HTML}{131418}
\definecolor{c25}{HTML}{00C0BF}
\definecolor{c26}{HTML}{140F13}
\definecolor{c27}{HTML}{C0C1BC}

\definecolor{c31}{HTML}{01204E}
\definecolor{c32}{HTML}{FEFEFE}
\definecolor{c33}{HTML}{34006C}
\definecolor{c34}{HTML}{141215}
\definecolor{c35}{HTML}{120403}
\definecolor{c36}{HTML}{151316}
\definecolor{c37}{HTML}{1E1C1F}
\definecolor{c38}{HTML}{141311}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach[count=\i] \col in {c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16,c17}
      \fill[\col] (10*\i,0) rectangle ++(10,-40);
\foreach[count=\i] \col in {c21,c22,c23,c24,c25,c26,c27}
      \fill[\col] (10*\i,-40) rectangle ++(10,-5);
\foreach[count=\i] \col in {c31,c32,c33,c34}
      \fill[\col] ([xshift=-2cm]12*\i,-45) rectangle ++(12,-12);
\foreach[count=\i] \col in {c35,c36,c37}
      \fill[\col] ([xshift=54cm]4*\i,-45) rectangle ++(4,-12);
\fill[black!90] (70,-45) rectangle ++(10,-12);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Update

The code can be further simplified to just one loop:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \col in {1,...,7}
{
      \fill[c1\col] (10*\col,0) rectangle ++(10,-40);
      \fill[c2\col] (10*\col,-40) rectangle ++(10,-5);
      \ifnum\col<5\relax
        \def\Shift{-2cm}\def\Ancho{12}
      \else
        \def\Shift{38cm}\def\Ancho{4}
      \fi  
      \fill[c3\col] 
        ([xshift=\Shift]\Ancho*\col,-45) rectangle ++(\Ancho,-12);
}
\fill[black] (70,-45) rectangle ++(10,-12);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And changing the widths for the strips in the lower part, one gets the result in the original image in the question:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \col in {1,...,7}
{
      \fill[c1\col] (10*\col,0) rectangle ++(10,-40);
      \fill[c2\col] (10*\col,-40) rectangle ++(10,-5);
      \ifnum\col<5\relax
        \def\Shift{-2.5cm}\def\Ancho{12.5}
      \else
        \def\Shift{43.35cm}\def\Ancho{10/3}
      \fi  
      \fill[c3\col] 
        ([xshift=\Shift]\Ancho*\col,-45) rectangle ++(\Ancho,-12);
}
\fill[black] (70,-45) rectangle ++(10,-12);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

### Remarks

- You had the x and y coordinates in the wrong order inside the loops.
- You needed some shifts for the lower strip.
- You were producing the figure upside-down; I changed the y-coordinates to have it in the proper direction.

Comment: @Dr.HenrietteB.Fröhlich You're welcome! I've updated my answer with a simplification that might be of interest.

Comment: @Dr.HenrietteB.Fröhlich New update. This time just one loop was used.

Answer (score 4):

It is hard to see your entire picture but I hope what I have done will help. The issue is that you need to increment x coordinate based on \i and not y. The x coordinate should be \i*n where n is the width of the rectangle.

```
\documentclass[margin=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{c11}{HTML}{C1BFC2}
\definecolor{c12}{HTML}{C0BF02}
\definecolor{c13}{HTML}{00C0C1}
\definecolor{c14}{HTML}{02BF01}
\definecolor{c15}{HTML}{BF00C0}
\definecolor{c16}{HTML}{C10001}
\definecolor{c17}{HTML}{0100C2}

\definecolor{c21}{HTML}{0300C3}
\definecolor{c22}{HTML}{141215}
\definecolor{c23}{HTML}{BF06C3}
\definecolor{c24}{HTML}{131418}
\definecolor{c25}{HTML}{00C0BF}
\definecolor{c26}{HTML}{140F13}
\definecolor{c27}{HTML}{C0C1BC}

\definecolor{c31}{HTML}{01204E}
\definecolor{c32}{HTML}{FEFEFE}
\definecolor{c33}{HTML}{34006C}
\definecolor{c34}{HTML}{141215}
\definecolor{c35}{HTML}{120403}
\definecolor{c36}{HTML}{151316}
\definecolor{c37}{HTML}{1E1C1F}
\definecolor{c38}{HTML}{141311}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach[count=\i] \col in {c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16,c17}
      \fill[\col] (\i*2,1) rectangle +(2,8);
\foreach[count=\i] \col in {c21,c22,c23,c24,c25,c26,c27}
      \fill[\col] (\i*2,0) rectangle +(2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```